# Vector Spaces with Spanning Sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble on solving this problem. I hope someone can help me start or show me the process on solving this problem. Thank you in advance.

The question is:

Let $W$ be the following subset of the vector space $P_3$ of polynomials of degree 3 or less,
$W = \left\lbrace p = \alpha_3x^3 + \alpha_2x^2 + \alpha_1x + \alpha_0 \in P_4 | p(0)=0, \alpha_2=\alpha_3 \right\rbrace$.
Prove that $W$ is a subspace of $P_3$ and find a linearly independent set $S$ such that $W=\left<S\right>$.

Comment: It might be easier for you to transform this into an $\mathbb R^4$ problem. Think about why $W\cong \{(a,a,b,0)|a,b\in\mathbb R\} \le \mathbb R^4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

To show that $W$ is a subspace, you need to show

1. $0\in W$
2. If $w\in W$ and $r\in R$, then $rw\in W$
3. If $w_1$ and $w_2$ are in $W$, then $w_1+w_2\in W$.

Do this by writing elements of $w$ as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ like DavidP suggested.

Once you have it in vector form, it should be easier to see the spanning set as well.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that something is a subspace of another, you can use the axioms of a subspace.

1. W is non-empty
2. for every **u**, **v** ∈ W, and c ∈ *R*: **u**+**v** ∈ W and c**u** ∈ W.